# How to pass logging level to custom monolog handler in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, monolog

I have *monolog* configuration like:

```
$container->loadFromExtension('monolog', [
    'handlers' => [
        'CustomMonologHandler' => [
            'type' => 'service',
            'level' => 'warning',
            'id' => \MyNamespace\Monolog\CustomMonologHandler::class
        ],
    ]
]);
```

and *service* is registered:

```
$container->register(
    \MyNamespace\Monolog\CustomMonologHandler::class,
    \MyNamespace\Monolog\CustomMonologHandler::class
)
    ->setFactory([\MyNamespace\Monolog\CustomMonologHandler::classFactory::class, 'get']);
```

and all works ok. But I want pass logging level (*e.g*. `'level' => 'warning'`) to `MyCustomHandler` and I don't have idea how to do that.

Is any way to create custom handler in other way? Or how I can pass this information to my handler?

I'm using:

```
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
"symfony/symfony": "^v3.3"
```